# Tkinter new window class functions causing TLCError Image does not exist

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to set a background image for a start screen in a tkinter class object however when I run the code that starts the app I get the following error image "pyimage6" doesn't exist. I researched and found out this is occurring because python is deleting the reference to the image so I made a variable to store it in however the error is still occurring when running the code.

What is strange is when I delete the two functions and buttons in the below code it works? I am not sure how I can preserve the two functions that create new windows and keep the background image for the canvas widget.

error on line 10
Error: TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist

Code for start screen and app initialization below

```
class Start_Screen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        image = PIL.Image.open('start_screen_pic.png')
        WIDTH, HEIGHT = image.size
        self.master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        self.start_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("start_screen_pic.png"))
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.start_img, anchor='nw')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Yelp review statistics', width = 25, command = self.Yelp_screen)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Instagram post analysis', width = 25, command = self.Insta_screen)
        
        
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        
    def Yelp_screen(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Yelp_screen_start(self.newWindow)
    def Insta_screen(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Insta_screen_start(self.newWindow)
```

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = Start_Screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing it correctly. Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: I have other classes that are creating new windows and functions within the class above that lead to those other classes could that be causing the issue I updated the code to show the other windows being created?

Comment: Ok so looks like when I delete the two functions and buttons below the app/image works and no error occurs/ however how can I get around this if I need buttons that lead to new windows?

Comment: Put `master=self.canvas` inside `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`

Comment: If you have multiple instances of `tk.Tk`, you should be passing in the `master` argument when creating `PhotoImages`. That way `tkinter` can know which base window(/interpreter) to assign the image to.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I copied it to a new workbook in jupyter notebook then re-ran the script and for some reason, it works with the exact same code in the new jupyter notebook and not in the old. I don't know why this happened in the old one but for now it's working in the new workbook. Sorry I don't have an exact answer as to why it is happening

Comment: When you reran this in the notebook, it cleared a cache somewhere. I ran into the same problem and fixed it by resetting the notebook or pycharm (which I was also using)